# Continuation code (ContinueWith) not getting executed

Tags: c#

I have the following code where the continuation code isn't getting executed.

```c#
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Konsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main starting...");

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Job1();
            })
            .ContinueWith(async t =>
            {
                await Job2();
            }).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Main ending...");
        }

        public static async Task Job1()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Job1 {i}");
                }
            });
        }

        public static async Task Job2()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Job2 {i}");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Main starting...
Job1 1
Job1 2
Main ending...
```

I expected Job2 to be executed as well before the application closed.

Comment: You shouldn't mix calls to `Thread.Sleep` and the async/await programming model.

Comment: @Sean That's true, but even if you replace the `Thread.Sleep()` with `await Task.Delay()` (and change the Task.Run to be async), you STILL get the same results.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I know, I'm just pointing out the issue of mixing the two.

Comment: @Sean I just added Thread.Sleep(1000) to simulate some long work being done for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer you question, you need to 'Unwrap' the task from the first async call as follows:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
         {
           await Job1();
         })
         .ContinueWith(async t =>
         {
           await Job2();
         })
         .Unwrap()
         .Wait();
```

[`Unwrap` Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap?view=netframework-4.8)

There are a number of other things to comment on here though.

If you are using async/await, you should really use it all the way through. Your question doesn't specify which version of c# you are using. If you are using [C# 7.1 or above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1), you should make your main method an async method as follows:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Main starting...");
  await Job1();
  await Job2();
  Console.WriteLine("Main ending...");
}
```

Also, as pointed out by @Sean, `Thread.Sleep` is a bad idea in these scenarios, you should use await `Task.Delay(1000);` instead.
[Task.Delay Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8)

A great article with some async/await best practices can be found on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) as well.

Comment: [Link to `Unwrap()` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was avoiding using async await because I wanted to better understand how ContinueWith worked. Your answer really helped clear the confusion as 'unwrap' was never mentioned in any of the courses I've watched in Pluralsight and Youtube that covered TAP.

Comment: This [pluralsight course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/getting-started-with-asynchronous-programming-dotnet/table-of-contents) really helped me. Also, [Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) is a great resource for these topics.

Answer (score 1):

[You should not use `ContinueWith`; it's a dangerous, low-level method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). In this case, you're encountering a problem because `ContinueWith` does not understand asynchronous delegates.

Ideally, you should replace all calls to `ContinueWith` (and `Wait`) with `await`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Main starting...");

  await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    await Job1();
  });
  await Job2();

  Console.WriteLine("Main ending...");
}
```

If you break out the variables so you can see the types, it will become more clear why the original code wasn't working:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Main starting...");

  Task runTask = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    await Job1();
  });
  Task<Task> continuationTask = runTask.ContinueWith(async t =>
  {
    await Job2();
  });

  // continuationTask is a Task<Task>.
  // This waits for the "outer" task only, not the "inner" task.
  continuationTask.Wait();

  Console.WriteLine("Main ending...");
}
```